# Set enum from NSDictionary Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, types, swift, enums

I have information stored in a plist file that I pull into a dictionary.

I have a class with some enums set up as follows:

```
enum componentPostion {
    case upperLeft, UpperRight, lowerLeft, lowerRight
}
```

I've declared a var as of type componentPostion

```
var isPosition: componentPostion
```

Can I then set the enum from the value in the dictionary without having to write a function with a switch statement etc. I've tried this with no luck

```
isPosition = componentInfo["Type"] as componentPostion
```

Comment: How is this dictionary declared?

Comment: IM creating a dictionary from a dictionary stored in a plist file as follows

let dict = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Cards", ofType: "plist")!)
componentInfo = dict.valueForKeyPath(componentName) as NSDictionary

in the plist file it is a string

Answer (score 1):

You can use raw values by inheriting the enum from the type you want to hold, in your case I presume it's string:

```
enum componentPostion : String{
    case upperLeft = "upperLeft"
    case upperRight = "upperRight"
    case lowerLeft = "lowerLeft"
    case lowerRight = "lowerRight"
}
```

Then you can use `fromRaw()` to obtain an enum case:

```
let isPosition = componentPostion.fromRaw("upperLeft")
```

and `toRaw()` to obtain its string representation

```
isPosition.toRaw()
```

Note that `fromRaw()` returns an optional, in case the parameter doesn't match any raw value defined for the enum

Suggested reading: [Raw Values](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Enumerations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH12-XID_228)